# Homework question. please give me hints or feedback

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Prove or ﬁnd a counterexample: For all real numbers x and y it holds that
x + y is irrational if, and only if, both x and y are irrational

Answer (score 3):

One direction is certainly false:

$$\pi + (-\pi) = 0$$

In this case, both $\pi$ and $-\pi$ are irrational, but $0$ is rational.

For the other direction, we can prove the contrapositive: if $x$ and $y$ are both rational, then is $x+y$ rational?  Certainly, since the rational numbers are closed under addition.

Comment: can you be more specific please, i am new to all this

Comment: Well,$\sqrt{2}+(-\sqrt{2})=0$ is most certainly rational although $\pm\sqrt{2}$ is definitely irrational.

Comment: The same comment about the contrapositive to Lemur applies here as well.

Answer (score 3):

We have the statement:

$x,y$ are irrational if and only if $x+y$ is irrational

If $x,y$ are irrational, then $x+y$ may not be irrational. For instance, we know $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational. Hence $x = \sqrt{2}$ and $y = - \sqrt{2} $ are both irrational, but $x+y = 0 $ is not irrational. Hence, $\implies$ is false.

Now, for the other direction, we want to show that given $x+y$ irrational, then $x$,$y$ are irrational. We can prove the contrapositive: assume $x,y$ are rational, and then we show $x+y$ is rational: To this end, suppose $x,y$ are rational. Hence, $x = \frac{p_1}{q_1}$ and $y = \frac{p_2}{q_2}$. Therefore,

$$ x+ y = \frac{p_1}{q_1} + \frac{p_2}{q_2} = \frac{p_1q_2 + q_1p_2}{q_1q_2} \in  \mathbb{Q}$$

Comment: Note on the proof by contraposition: the statement "if A is true then B is true" is the same as "if B is false than A is false".

Comment: Your contrapositive bit is slightly wrong - the negation of "both $x$ and $y$ are irrational" is "at least one of $x$ and $y$ is rational", not "both $x$ and $y$ are rational", as you currently have. You can clearly have $x+y$ irrational, $x$ irrational, $y$ rational.

Answer (score 1):

For two real numbers x, y, the following is NOT TRUE:

$$x + y \notin Q \implies (x \notin Q \land y\notin Q)\tag{false}$$

Why false? Suppose we look at the contrapositive:  $$(x \in Q \text{ or } y \in Q) \implies x+y \in Q$$ which must also be false. To see this: Take $x = 2$, $y = \sqrt 2$. Then the premise is satisfied, but $x + y = 2+\sqrt 2 \notin Q$.